# Any Ideas for Predicting Multiple Linear Regression Coefficients by using Neural Networks (ANN)?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, linear-regression, backpropagation, perceptron

In case, there are 2 inputs (`X1` and `X2`) and 1 target output (`t`) to be estimated by neural network (each nodes has 6 samples):

```
X1 = [2.765405915 2.403146899 1.843932529 1.321474515 0.916837222 1.251301467]; 

X2 = [84870 363024 983062 1352580 804723 845200];

t = [-0.12685144347197 -0.19172223428950 -0.29330584684934 -0.35078062276141 0.03826908777226 0.06633047875487];
```

I was trying to find the best fit of `t` prediction by using multiple linear regression (Ordinary Least Squares or OLS) manually and the outcomes were pretty good.

I intend to find the a, b, c (regression coefficients) from this equation:

```
t = a + b*X1 + c*X2
```

Since the equation is the basic form of multiple linear regression equation with two regressors, of course I could find the value of a, b, c by doing the OLS.

The problem is: I've tried to find the regression coefficients by using neural network (with MATLAB `nftool` and train it by Levenberg-Marquardt Backpropagation or `lmtrain`) **but** have no idea how to find them, though the outcomes were showing less error than the OLS.

Then, several questions that comes:

1. Is it possible to find the regression coefficient by using neural network?
2. If it's possible, What kind of ANN algorithm that could solve this kind of problem and how to build it manually?

If you have any ideas how to solve it, please help. I really need your help!

This is the script that generated by MATLAB `nftool` that I used to fit the output estimation:

```
% Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network
% Script generated by NFTOOL
% Created Fri Jun 05 06:26:36 ICT 2015
%
% This script assumes these variables are defined:
%
%   x - input data.
%   t - target data.
x = [2.765405915 2.403146899 1.843932529 1.321474515 0.916837222 1.251301467; 84870 363024 983062 1352580 804723 845200];
t = [-0.12685144347197 -0.19172223428950 -0.29330584684934 -0.35078062276141 0.03826908777226 0.06633047875487];

inputs = x;
targets = t;

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);


% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 90/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 5/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 5/100;


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotfit(net,inputs,targets)
%figure, plotregression(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrhist(errors)
```

Comment: Post the code you used when you tried using `nftool` etc...

Comment: Ok, immediately! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neural network will generally not find or encode a formula like `t = a + b*X1 + c*X2`, unless you built a really simple one with no hidden layers and linear output. If you did then you could read the values `[a,b,c]` from the weights attached to bias, input 1 and input 2. However, such a network offers no advantage over linear regression (essentially it *is* linear regression using NN tools to build it and comparatively slow gradient descent to find the lowest least-square error when it can be done in a single pass in OLS).

What you have built instead is a more complex non-linear function. Most likely the error is low because you have over-fit your data, which is very easy to do with a neural net. With your input data as shown, it should be possible to get an training error of 0, but that is not as good as it seems - it just means the neural network has found a complex surface that connects all your examples, which is probably of limited use as a predictive model.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, sir! Roger that! :)
So, do you have any recommendations of method (still talks about AI) that could be used to find the `[a,b,c]` and gives a great challage to the OLS in order to find them?

Comment: OLS should be optimal for regression problem when you have a simple linear model. Your options for a better predictor generally involve looking at more complex models. Also, you usually require more data than your example in order to discover whether a more complex model is worth the effort.

Comment: Got it! So, in other words there's no need to use another predictor for this case. Thank you for the comment, sir!

Comment: But by any chance, is there any method that could be use for estimating the `[a,b,c]`? If possible, I just want to make a fine comparison of both results.

Comment: The normal equation `pinv( x * x' ) * x * t'` should give you exact values of `[a,b,c]` (I realise I was assuming that is what you are doing to get the OLS result - remember to add a row of 1's to get a value for `a` - I get    `[8.2860e-01, -3.3193e-01, -5.2864e-07]` from your data for comparison). You can also fit a neural network with no hidden layer and use the bias weight for `a` and look at the input weights for `b` and `c`.

Comment: Wow, It works! That's the answer for the questions that I wanted to know. I used to be curious about what kind of method used by MATLAB to estimate the values of `[a,b,c]` by the `cftool` and finally got the exact answer from you. Very clear! Thank you again for your great response, sir!

Comment: By the way, I think the normal equation is the very basic concept of linear least square. Just for discussion, I got a slighly better results with less error for the estimation by doing the Ordinary Least Squares under Multiple Linear Regression. I get `[0.67272757, -0.276768133, -4.65622E-07]`. You can simply try to find it by using `Regression` in MS. Excel Data Analysis Tools.

Comment: I have been trying to fit a neural net with no hidden layer and use the `a` as bias, `b` and `c` as input weights, but the outcome was terrible. 

Actually, I used the delta rule for bias and weights correction. Beside that, I used `tansig` for the activation function. That's make the ANN's architecture looks like Perceptron, but with modified activation function. So, do you have any idea for what kind of bias and weights correction that leads to good estimation of it? And is it wrong if I use the `tansig` for the activation function?

Comment: Don't use tansig, use a linear output, otherwise you are not finding the correct `[a,b,c]` but params for a different model that you don't want. Delta rule should be fine. I would expect the result to be worse (but not much worse) than Normal Equation. You need low learning rate (alpha) and large number of iterations, and may need to try different values before you find stable ones.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, sir! You're the best! Finally I got a good estimation of `[a,b,c]` by using the neural net after following your recommendation of the simple architecture above. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me! I really appreciate it! I believe that your attention to detail puts you at the top of your career, sir! :)